# Circuit breakers per server in Traefik

Tags: traefik

According to the documentation, [circuit breakers](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#circuit-breakers) operate at the backend level. I was wondering if it's possible to set circuit breakers per server.

If I understand correctly if the circuit breaker is switched on (a server returning 500 errors), then the entire backend is disabled. Instead, with circuit breakers per server, only the problematic server will be removed from the pool.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you received an answer elsewhere on this? I am equally baffled by entire backend being disabled.